# vb.net wRequest loop to each link in array of string

Tags: arrays, vb.net, webrequest, webresponse

if i can make `WebRequest` for one link like this :

```
    Dim rt As String = "http://www.somelink.com"
    Dim wRequest As WebRequest
    Dim WResponse As WebResponse
    Dim SR As StreamReader
    wRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(rt)
    WResponse = wRequest.GetResponse
    SR = New StreamReader(WResponse.GetResponseStream)
    rt = SR.ReadToEnd
```

how can i make a loop or function of `WebRequest`for an array of links or array of string 
and return for me `WebResponse` for each link in one string or array of string

Answer (score 0):

ok i find the answer

```
    Dim SR As StreamReader
For i As Int32 = 0 To myarr.Length - 1
    Dim wRequest As WebRequest
    Dim WResponse As WebResponse
    wRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(myarr(i))
    WResponse = wRequest.GetResponse
    SR = New StreamReader(WResponse.GetResponseStream)
    myarr(i) = SR.ReadToEnd

Next
```